# Powershell choking on cyrillic т

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This works:

```
$mapping = ('а', 'б', 'в')

foreach ($i in $mapping) {
  Write-Host $i
}
```

This throws a bunch of errors:

```
$mapping = ('а', 'б', 'т')

foreach ($i in $mapping) {
  Write-Host $i
}
```

The only difference between the two snippets is the third char in `mapping` is `т`. Powershell parses the first two chars so it can obviously parse Cyrillic, but it chokes on letter `т`. Why does this happen, and can this be solved or worked around?

The errors are `The string is missing the terminator: '.`, `Missing closing ')' in expression.` What I'm getting from this is it reads everything that comes after `т` as part of the string.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.. Are you saving the script in UTF-8 ? Also, you don;t need the brackets when defining an array. The commas between the values is enough: `$mapping = 'а', 'б', 'т'`

Comment: Apologies, the snippet is a simplified version of a larger piece of code. I am using a 2d array there, and the parenths are a remnant of that. Yes, the script is in UTF-8. Are you saying both versions produce no errors for you? I've tested on two different Windows 10 builds, and both threw errors.

Comment: I've just recreated the same script using Notepad (was using VSCode before so thought maybe that's the culprit), but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? I tested with version 5.1 and get no errors. I see you also tagged `powershell 2.0`.. Are you really using that?

Comment: No I'm using 5.1 too. There just wasn't a powershell 5.1 tag in selection so I chose.. 2.0. Pretty stupid I admit, not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @Theo I think there's something wrong with the file or the characters that caused it to not only error out on letter `т` specifically, but also have a weird console output (`Ð°` `Ð±` `Ð²` for `а` `б` `в`) for the chars it _was_ working with. I somehow missed this but the newly created file _does_ work. It doesn't choke on letter `т`, but also the console output was normal ( `а` `б` `в`). I've uploaded both files in case anyone has the time or desire to figure out what went wrong and how to avoid this in the future: https://www.mediafire.com/file/b8t1mgw0oofufuo/test_files.zip/file